# Is there anyway to requestLocationUpdates fast using GPS_PROVIDER in android

Tags: android, gps, location

I am trying to get the location updates but it takes anything between 30 seconds - 5 mins. So i decided to throw in coarse location which is faster and run the GPS_PROVIDER in background. But no luck. As of now after the coarse location is executed, the control never goes to onLocationChanged in GPS_PROVIDER listener. Is there some way to get the updates faster, so the user does not have to wai long?

Answer (score 2):

You can use NETWORK_PROVIDER to get fast location

Comment: Well...i made the code work with the same idea mentioned in the question..so now i get location updates faster and after few seconds i get the GPS locations to get the accuracy...

Comment: I did the same thing i mentioned in my question..but juggling between NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER. So when the user starts application for the first time, it will push COARSE_LOCATION and start GPS_PROVIDER in the background...The second run will have the accurate location...on every run i also check the last NETWORK_PROVIDER location to find out the user has changed his/her location...if same then go with the last known GPS values else push coarse location again and start GPS in background... it works fine and serves the purpose...fast and accurate to an extent...

Answer (score 0):

and there is no way to to update fast as it depends on hardware

NETWORK_PROVIDER gives fast as compared to that , but you there must be active network in there .

Comment: how bad the accuracy can be in crowded city if i use NETWORK_PROVIDER.. right now its 1500 m in Atlanta

Comment: NETWORK_PROVIDER accuracy depends on a number of factors. In my experience, GSM phones will be more accurate than CDMA in the US. Keep in mind, depending on how your phone is configured, NETWORK may also match on WiFi hotspots, which can often have accuracy < 100m.